# sum of binary tree at a specific depth

Tags: java, recursion

I am trying to recursively traverse a tree and return the sum of a given depth. Say I want the sum at depth = 2, it should recurse and subtract 1 until depth is 0, which then will add that node to the sum. It keeps summing the whole tree instead of just one level and I'm not sure where the mistake is. Also, I am supposed to use the interface ReduceFunction.

```
public interface ReduceFunction<InT,OutT> {

    public OutT combine(OutT soFar, InT x);     

    public OutT initialValue();
}

public T reduce(int n, ReduceFunction<T,T> f) {
        return rdceHelper(n, root, f, f.initialValue());               
}

private T rdceHelper(int depth, TreeNode<T> node, ReduceFunction<T,T> f, T sum){
    if(node == null || depth < 0){
        return f.initialValue();
    }

    if(depth == 0){
        sum = f.combine(sum, node.data);
    }

    if(node.left != null){
        sum = f.combine(sum, rdceHelper(depth-1, node.left, f, sum));
    }
    if(node.right != null){
        sum = f.combine(sum, rdceHelper(depth-1, node.right, f, sum));
    }

    return sum;
}
```

Comment: You can find the solution at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3020070/how-to-find-sum-of-nodes-value-for-given-depth-in-binary-tree

Comment: I have to follow some guidelines including using a variable sum as well as use the interface above.  I can't stray away from those parameters.

Answer (score 0):

ok. I don't have the source code hence not able to validate following solution. I don't think we need sum variable. We can take care of that if we are using recursion. If you still want to use, then pass value '0'.

Can you modify your code to following and check,

```
    if(depth == 0){
        return f.combine(0, node.data);
    }else{
        return f.combine(0, rdceHelper(depth-1, node.left, f, 0)) + 
        f.combine(0, rdceHelper(depth-1, node.right, f, 0));
    }
```

Comment: i figured it out on my own, thanks for the help though.

Comment: While this works on a complete binary tree, it doesn't work on a depth that doesn't have a complete child leafs, how do I make this so that it also counts the leafs on the last depth (the one where it's not a complete maximum child leafs)?